# Notation for sorting multidimensional array with usort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I wish to sort the following array `$json_a` (which was decoded from a json file) firstly by `match_formatted_date` and then by `match_localteam_name`.

```
array(4) { 

 ["APIRequestsRemaining"]=> int(920) 
 ["matches"]=> array(3) { 

                [0]=> array(3) { 
                      ["match_id"]=> string(7) "1999477" 
                      ["match_formatted_date"]=> string(6) "16.05.2015" 
                        ["match_localteam_name"]=> string(7) "Burnley"  } 

                [1]=> array(3) { 
                       ["match_id"]=> string(7) "1999478" 
                       ["match_formatted_date"]=> string(10) "16.05.2015" 
                        ["match_localteam_name"]=> string(3) "QPR" 
                        } 

                [2]=> array(3) { 
                       ["match_id"]=> string(7) "1999479" 
                       ["match_formatted_date"]=> string(10) "16.05.2015" 
                        ["match_localteam_name"]=> string(7) "Arsenal" 
                        } 
         } 
 ["Action"]=> string(5) "today" 
         }
```

I have tried to call a function to usort as follows:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    // sort by ['match_formatted_date']
    $retval = strnatcmp(substr($b['match_formatted_date'],0,10), substr($a['match_formatted_date'],0,10));

    // if identical, sort by ['match_localteam_name']
    if(!$retval) $retval = strnatcmp($a['match_localteam_name'], $b['match_localteam_name']);

    return $retval;
}

$matches = $json_a['matches'];
usort($matches, 'cmp');
```

However, it does not seem to be sorting the records. I have read as much as a can about usort but I suspect that the problem lies in the notation format in my function. I have also tried `$a['matches']['match_date']` but no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should turn your dates into timestamps and compare those instead of the raw strings.

Replace this:

```
// sort by ['match_formatted_date']
$retval = strnatcmp(substr($b['match_formatted_date'],0,10), substr($a['match_formatted_date'],0,10));
```

With this:

```
// sort by ['match_formatted_date']
$retval =
    strtotime($a['match_formatted_date'])
    - strtotime($b['match_formatted_date']);
```

Comment: Ticked as answer as it both noted the issue and offered suggestion for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to sort the entries by first comparing the dates. However, if your dates have the format `16.05.2015`, using `strnatcmp()`, you will always first sort by day of month, then by month and finally by year, which does not really make any sense whatsoever. Even worse, you also mix a date with the format `May 16` in there, which compares even worse to the first format.

Before comparing them, you have to convert your dates into a common format like `Ymd`, e.g. `20150516` in order to enable a correct comparison. You also have to decide how to take care of `May 16`, where you don't even have a date -- should it come before or after May 15th, 2016?

Comment: May 16 was a transcription error, should have been 16.05.2015. Have corrected in question.

Comment: Please post a `var_dump` of the resulting array after the `usort()`